# Sprint Boot ProducerTemplate as constructor parameter failing

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, junit

**Edit: I've been told by my lead that the test that called the class I was having issues with utilized BPMS and that BPMS is no longer used for the project. Thank you for all of the replies.**

Background:

I'm working with an existing codebase, which still isn't fully functional. Specifically, I've been tasked with getting the project's unit tests completed, but I've had no previous experience with Spring or dependency managers at all.

Problem:

The code given below is causing my tests to not compile, saying there's no qualifying bean of `ProducerTemplate`.

```
@Component
public class QueueService {

    @Produce
    private ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

    public QueueService(ProducerTemplate producerTemplate) {
        this.producerTemplate = producerTemplate;
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if this is a dumb question, but I haven't been able to find another instance of this in a question.

[Stack Trace](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AY65.png)

Comment: Do you have a configuration for `ProducerTemplate` class? And you don't need `@Produce` annotation in order to inject `ProducerTemplate`. Also please share the exact stack trace.

Comment: @Boris I have edited the post for the stack trace. I removed the ```@Produce``` annotation, but I'm not sure if there is a configuration file for that class.

Comment: Spring expects a bean of type [ProducerTemplate](https://camel.apache.org/maven/current/camel-core/apidocs/org/apache/camel/ProducerTemplate.html) declaration and it's missing.

Answer (score 0):

Spring Boot component provides auto-configuration for Apache Camel. For integration using Apache Camel you must add a starter dependency:

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
  <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
  <version>2.22.1</version>
</dependency>
```

See [here](http://camel.apache.org/spring-boot.html) for more info. A [tutorial](http://How%20to%20Integrate%20Spring%20Boot%20and%20Apache%20Camel) on the subject.